# Convert IMG to ISO

Tags: iso

Made an image file of one of my Ubuntu partitions using Ubuntu's "Disks" utility, and I need to turn that into an ISO. CCD2ISO wouldn't do it ("Unrecognized sector mode (0) at sector 0!"), and AcetoneISO also wouldn't do it ("Process Error Code: 255").

Can anyone shed light on what is going on?

Comment: Why do you need to turn it to an ISO? Rufus, Etcher, dd, mkusb, etc will install from an .img file.

Comment: Ventoy doesn't boot IMG files created using Ubuntu's "Disks" utility, only ISOs. (And yes, I've learned my lesson, from now on I will be creating only ISOs.)

Comment: Do you want a USB to run multi OS or to install them. It is easy to make a multi OS installer that uses .img files.